# React native text inside of image

Tags: react-native

I am making an image gallery react native application. I was able to put the image but I wanted to add a text at the bottom of each image but I don't know how. Here is my code:

```
state = {
    images: [
        require('../../assets/image1.png'),
        require('../../assets/image2.png'),
        require('../../assets/image3.png'),
        require('../../assets/image4.png'),
        require('../../assets/image5.png'),
        require('../../assets/image6.png'),
        require('../../assets/image7.png'),
        require('../../assets/image8.png'),
    ],
    text: [text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6,text7,text8]
}

let images = this.state.images.map((val, key) => {
        return <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={key}>
                    <View style={styles.imagewrap}>
                        <ImageElement imgsource={val} />
                        <Text style={{position:'absolute'}}> {this.state.text.map((data) => {
                            return data
                        })} </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
});
```

So what happens is, it prints out the text 'text1text2text3text4.....' for all the images instead of 'text1' for image 1, 'text2' for image 2 and so on. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the second param in a map callback (what you have called "key") is the index of the current element (called "val" in your code). What you need to do is in your Text element, instead of mapping through all of your text, just render the text at the current index.  So instead of `{this.state.text.map((data) => {return data})}` 
Just do
`{this.state.text[key]}`

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much